# CORS did not succeed in Node.js AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, cors

### Cross-Origin Request Blocked

The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xx.xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/endpointurl. .
I'm using Node.js, AWS EC2 and Vue frontend

> (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

How can I enable CORS ?

In console I'm able to see another error also

> Loading mixed (insecure) active content on a secure page

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add it as a dependency:

```
npm install --save cors
```

And then use it as middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
/* your regular routes go here */
```

That’s it. CORS is now enabled.

If you make a request to your app, you will notice a new header being returned:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header determines which origins are allowed to access server resources over CORS (the * wildcard allows access from any origin).

Comment: You need to pass the url from which you will be requesting from